C++ static vector implementation
This is my custom static vector implementation similar to Boost’s StaticVector. Basically the idea is that the container should have a fixed compile time capacity, never dynamically allocates but should otherwise behave like a std::vector. Please kindly offer any suggestions/improvements to the code.
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <iterator>
#include <cstddef>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>
#include <limits>
#include <algorithm>

template<std::size_t Capacity>
using SizeType = typename std::conditional_t<
    (Capacity <= std::numeric_limits<uint8_t>::max()), uint8_t,
    typename std::conditional_t<
        (Capacity <= std::numeric_limits<uint16_t>::max()), uint16_t,
        typename std::conditional_t<
            (Capacity <= std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max()), uint32_t,
            uint64_t
        >
    >
>;

template<typename T, std::size_t Capacity>
class StaticVector {
public:
    using value_type = T;
    using iterator = T*;
    using const_iterator = const T*;
    using size_type = SizeType<Capacity>;

    static constexpr bool is_raw_storage = !std::is_trivially_constructible<T>::value;

    StaticVector() : size_(0) {}

    ~StaticVector() {
        clear();
    }

    iterator push_back(const T& value) {
        if (size_ >= Capacity) {
            return end();  // Return end() to indicate failure
        }
        if constexpr (is_raw_storage) {
            new (buffer(size_)) T(value);
        } else {
            data_[size_] = value;
        }
        return aligned_buffer(size_++);
    }

    template<typename... Args>
    iterator emplace_back(Args&&... args) {
        if (size_ >= Capacity) {
            return end();  // Return end() to indicate failure
        }
        if constexpr (is_raw_storage) {
            new (buffer(size_)) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        } else {
            data_[size_] = T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }
        return aligned_buffer(size_++);
    }

    iterator insert(const_iterator pos, const T& value) {
        size_type idx = pos - cbegin();
        if (idx > size_ || size_ >= Capacity) {
            return end();  // Return end() to indicate failure
        }
        if constexpr (is_raw_storage) {
            new (buffer(size_)) T(std::move(*aligned_buffer(size_ - 1)));
            std::move_backward(begin() + idx, end() - 1, end());
            *aligned_buffer(idx) = value;
        } else {
            std::move_backward(begin() + idx, end(), end() + 1);
            data_[idx] = value;
        }
        ++size_;
        return aligned_buffer(idx);
    }

    iterator erase(const_iterator pos) {
        size_type idx = pos - cbegin();
        if (idx >= size_) {
            return end();  // Return end() to indicate failure
        }
        if constexpr (is_raw_storage) {
            aligned_buffer(idx)->~T();
            std::move(begin() + idx + 1, end(), begin() + idx);
        } else {
            std::move(begin() + idx + 1, end(), begin() + idx);
        }
        --size_;
        return aligned_buffer(idx);
    }

    void clear() {
        if constexpr (is_raw_storage) {
            for (size_type i = 0; i < size_; ++i) {
                aligned_buffer(i)->~T();
            }
        }
        size_ = 0;
    }

    iterator begin() {
        return aligned_buffer(0);
    }
    const_iterator begin() const {
        return aligned_buffer(0);
    }
    const_iterator cbegin() const {
        return begin();
    }

    iterator end() {
        return aligned_buffer(size_);
    }
    const_iterator end() const {
        return aligned_buffer(size_);
    }
    const_iterator cend() const {
        return end();
    }

    size_type size() const {
        return size_;
    }
    std::size_t capacity() const {
        return Capacity;
    }
    bool empty() const {
        return size_ == 0;
    }

    T& operator[](size_type index) {
        return *aligned_buffer(index);
    }
    const T& operator[](size_type index) const {
        return *aligned_buffer(index);
    }

private:
    // Helper type trait to choose between array of T or raw bytes
    using StorageType = typename std::conditional_t<
        std::is_trivially_constructible<T>::value,
        T[Capacity],
        alignas(alignof(T)) unsigned char[sizeof(T) * Capacity]
    >;

    // Returns a void* to the next available memory location
    void* buffer(size_type index = 0) {
        return &data_[index * sizeof(T)];
    }

    // Returns a T* to the next available memory location
    T* aligned_buffer(size_type index = 0) {
        if constexpr (is_raw_storage) {
            return reinterpret_cast<T*>(buffer(index));
        } else {
            return &data_[index];
        }
    }

    StorageType data_;
    size_type size_;
};

// Example usage
struct NonTrivial {
    int a;
    NonTrivial(int a) : a(a) { std::cout << "Constructed: " << a << "\n"; }
    ~NonTrivial() { std::cout << "Destructed: " << a << "\n"; }
};

int main() {
    StaticVector<int, 5> trivVec;
    trivVec.push_back(1);
    trivVec.push_back(2);
    trivVec.emplace_back(3);
    trivVec.insert(trivVec.cbegin() + 1, 4);
    trivVec.erase(trivVec.cbegin() + 2);

    std::cout << "Trivial vector contents: ";
    for (const auto& elem : trivVec) {
        std::cout << elem << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    StaticVector<NonTrivial, 5> nonTrivVec;
    nonTrivVec.push_back(NonTrivial(1));
    nonTrivVec.push_back(NonTrivial(2));
    nonTrivVec.emplace_back(3);
    nonTrivVec.insert(nonTrivVec.cbegin() + 1, NonTrivial(4));
    nonTrivVec.erase(nonTrivVec.cbegin() + 2);

    std::cout << "Non-trivial vector contents: ";
    for (const auto& elem : nonTrivVec) {
        std::cout << elem.a << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}


A static vector, is it meant to be used like an array but with all std::vector's methods?

@Harith Yes essentially a fixed capacity vector with inline storage. Unlike a std::array it does not default construct elements upfront, only allocating their memory.

Unnecessary "optimizations"
There is no need to distinguish between trivially and non-trivially constructible types. For a trivially constructible type, new (buffer(size_)) T(value) has exactly the same effect as data_[size_] = value, and with compiler optimizations enabled (even just -O1), it will result in the same assembly code. The same goes for all your other code.
You also change SizeType based on Capacity. However, unless Capacity is very small and T itself is also a very small type, there is little to no gain from this. You also make things harder for the caller, because they might get warnings about comparisons between integers of different size if they work with std::size_t consistently. If you want to keep storing the size as a small integer, consider that an implementation detail, and make the public interface use std::size_t.
Safety
In many functions you check if size_ or idx exceeds Capacity, and if so you return end(). You might think this prevents out of bounds writes, but now the caller has to check the return value and do the right thing every time it calls one of the member functions that returns an iterator. Consider a caller that doesn't:
StaticVector<int, 1> vec;
vec.push_back(1);                       // works
vec.push_back(2);                       // silently drops the 2
std::cout << *vec.push_back(3) << '\n'; // out-of-bounds read

I would either not do any checks at all, and leave it up to the caller to do bounds checking (it has to do anyway in your current code), or instead make your code throw exceptions; the latter will ensure an unhandled exception will terminate the program instead of getting undefined behavior.
Related to this:
Add an at() member function
Despite most member functions doing bounds checks, your operator[] does not. This is fine, that is exactly how it works for std::vector. But the latter also has at() which does do bounds checks.
Add the rest of std::vector's API
Your code already follows std::vector's API, which is great. However, it is missing a lot of its constructor overloads, member functions and member types. If you implement the remaining parts of the API, your StaticVector will become a real drop-in replacement for std::vector.

I made all the changes you suggested. See my answer. Would love to hear more feedback!

I posted a separate question regarding the revised implementation. Please take a look! https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/292509/c-static-vector-revised-implementation

Frame Challenge
It is already possible to give std::vector a custom allocator that does this kind of arena allocation.  A std::array would be a good alternative for everything but a stack, and you can track an i value for a std::array much more easily than writing a new class.
Act Like a std::vector that Fails to Resize
The std::vector API that you’re mostly following has std::vector::push_back return void.  This is also how other standard-library containers with it work.  No C++ programmer (or existing algorithm) ever expects push_back to have a return value that they need to check. They (and the compiler) will just silently ignore the return value out of habit.
It is therefore a huge surprise that the only way to detect failure is to store the original result of end(), attempt to push_back, and compare the new end() to the old one. What you actually want to do is throw an exception.  If you want to duplicate the behavior of std::vector exactly, that would be std::bad_alloc("StaticVector arena capacity exceeded"), but client code might actually try to handle that one by freeing a bunch of memory and retrying.  Since the user chose Capacity with a contract that it would be sufficient, you might instead classify exceeding it at runtime as a std::logic_error.
There is No Reason for the Pointer Conversions
Your aligned_buffer could much more simply be a T[Capacity].  On some CPUs, you can optimize by aligning the array to the native vector width.  You might have the <experimental/simd> header with std::experimental::memory_alignment. If not, you would need to roll one yourself by detecting the target architecture with macros like:
#if (__x86_64__ || _M_X64 || __i386__ || _M_IX86)
#  if __AVX512F__ 
    constexpr std::size_t vec_alignment = 64;
#  elif __AVX2__
    constexpr std::size_t vec_alignment = 32;
#  else // AVX or SSE.
    constexpr std::size_t vec_alignment = 16;
#  endif
/* Check for other architectures here. */
#else
    constexpr std::size_t vec_alignment = alignof(std::max_align_t);
#endif

Then align the array to max(vec_alignment, alignof(T)).
You Move the Arbitrary Type as Plain Old Data
In you comments, you clarify that a primary motivation not to use std::array is that T could be an arbitrary type that’s complicated to default-construct.
However, you then assume that the bytes of the object representation can be moved to a different memory location, which is not safe in general. (What if the reason for the expensive default construction is that the implementaion registers each object as it is created, and looks up the address later?)  You might mean std::uninitialized_move.
If the implementation does depend on T being trivially moveable, make std::is_trivially_move_constructible<T> an explicit constraint.

Thank you for your response. Regarding the comparison between std::array and StaticVector. I think a key difference is that a std array allocates AND constructs upfront while the static vector only allocates. This distinction is important for types that are non-default constructible or expensive to default construct. In my opinion, a std vector with stack allocator doesn't replace the need for a static vector in that a "stack vector" doe not own the storage while static vector does, which is important for ensuring correct copy/move semantics.

But you are completely correct about the weird API design. I will fix it now...

@ALLANZHANG Thanks for clarifying your requirements. Have you considered an implementation that encapsulates an arena plua a std::vector that allocates from the arena? This has the correct copy semantics (a large array of objects that are expensive to default-construct is not really moveable, and indeed, an arbitrary T might not be copyable or moveable).

@ALLANZHANG Which reminded me of a potential bug.

I get some warnings when I compile this code:
g++-14 -std=c++23 -fPIC -gdwarf-4 -g -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wno-parentheses -Wpedantic -Warray-bounds -Wmissing-braces -Wconversion  -Wuseless-cast -Weffc++       292356.cpp    -o 292356
292356.cpp:147:5: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument ‘unsigned char [(sizeof (T) * Capacity)]’ [-Wignored-attributes]
  147 |     >;
      |     ^
292356.cpp: In instantiation of ‘T* StaticVector<T, Capacity>::insert(const_iterator, const T&) [with T = int; long unsigned int Capacity = 5; iterator = int*; const_iterator = const int*]’:
292356.cpp:179:19:   required from here
292356.cpp:147:5: warning:   179 |     trivVec.insert(trivVec.cbegin() + 1, 4);
292356.cpp:147:5: warning:       |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
292356.cpp:64:29: warning: conversion from ‘long int’ to ‘StaticVector<int, 5>::size_type’ {aka ‘unsigned char’} may change value [-Wconversion]
   64 |         size_type idx = pos - cbegin();
      |                         ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
292356.cpp: In instantiation of ‘T* StaticVector<T, Capacity>::erase(const_iterator) [with T = int; long unsigned int Capacity = 5; iterator = int*; const_iterator = const int*]’:
292356.cpp:180:18:   required from here
292356.cpp:64:29: warning:   180 |     trivVec.erase(trivVec.cbegin() + 2);
292356.cpp:64:29: warning:       |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
292356.cpp:81:29: warning: conversion from ‘long int’ to ‘StaticVector<int, 5>::size_type’ {aka ‘unsigned char’} may change value [-Wconversion]
   81 |         size_type idx = pos - cbegin();
      |                         ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
292356.cpp: In instantiation of ‘T* StaticVector<T, Capacity>::insert(const_iterator, const T&) [with T = NonTrivial; long unsigned int Capacity = 5; iterator = NonTrivial*; const_iterator = const NonTrivial*]’:
292356.cpp:192:22:   required from here
292356.cpp:81:29: warning:   192 |     nonTrivVec.insert(nonTrivVec.cbegin() + 1, NonTrivial(4));
292356.cpp:81:29: warning:       |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
292356.cpp:64:29: warning: conversion from ‘long int’ to ‘StaticVector<NonTrivial, 5>::size_type’ {aka ‘unsigned char’} may change value [-Wconversion]
   64 |         size_type idx = pos - cbegin();
      |                         ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
292356.cpp: In instantiation of ‘T* StaticVector<T, Capacity>::erase(const_iterator) [with T = NonTrivial; long unsigned int Capacity = 5; iterator = NonTrivial*; const_iterator = const NonTrivial*]’:
292356.cpp:193:21:   required from here
292356.cpp:64:29: warning:   193 |     nonTrivVec.erase(nonTrivVec.cbegin() + 2);
292356.cpp:64:29: warning:       |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
292356.cpp:81:29: warning: conversion from ‘long int’ to ‘StaticVector<NonTrivial, 5>::size_type’ {aka ‘unsigned char’} may change value [-Wconversion]
   81 |         size_type idx = pos - cbegin();
      |                         ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
292356.cpp: In instantiation of ‘const T* StaticVector<T, Capacity>::begin() const [with T = int; long unsigned int Capacity = 5; const_iterator = const int*]’:
292356.cpp:111:21:   required from ‘const T* StaticVector<T, Capacity>::cbegin() const [with T = int; long unsigned int Capacity = 5; const_iterator = const int*]’
292356.cpp:81:29: warning:   111 |         return begin();
292356.cpp:81:29: warning:       |                ~~~~~^~
292356.cpp:179:34:   required from here
292356.cpp:81:29: warning:   179 |     trivVec.insert(trivVec.cbegin() + 1, 4);
292356.cpp:81:29: warning:       |                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~

These are easy to address.
There's also a couple of errors:
292356.cpp:108:30: error: passing ‘const StaticVector<int, 5>’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
  108 |         return aligned_buffer(0);
      |                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
292356.cpp:155:8: note:   in call to ‘T* StaticVector<T, Capacity>::aligned_buffer(size_type) [with T = int; long unsigned int Capacity = 5; size_type = unsigned char]’
  155 |     T* aligned_buffer(size_type index = 0) {
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
292356.cpp: In instantiation of ‘const T* StaticVector<T, Capacity>::begin() const [with T = NonTrivial; long unsigned int Capacity = 5; const_iterator = const NonTrivial*]’:
292356.cpp:111:21:   required from ‘const T* StaticVector<T, Capacity>::cbegin() const [with T = NonTrivial; long unsigned int Capacity = 5; const_iterator = const NonTrivial*]’
292356.cpp:155:8: note:   111 |         return begin();
292356.cpp:155:8: note:       |                ~~~~~^~
292356.cpp:192:40:   required from here
292356.cpp:155:8: note:   192 |     nonTrivVec.insert(nonTrivVec.cbegin() + 1, NonTrivial(4));
292356.cpp:155:8: note:       |                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
292356.cpp:108:30: error: passing ‘const StaticVector<NonTrivial, 5>’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
  108 |         return aligned_buffer(0);
      |                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
292356.cpp:155:8: note:   in call to ‘T* StaticVector<T, Capacity>::aligned_buffer(size_type) [with T = NonTrivial; long unsigned int Capacity = 5; size_type = unsigned char]’
  155 |     T* aligned_buffer(size_type index = 0) {
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~

To fix these, we need some const overloads:
    void const* buffer(size_type index = 0) const {
        return &data_[index * sizeof(T)];
    }

    T const* aligned_buffer(size_type index = 0) const {
        if constexpr (is_raw_storage) {
            return reinterpret_cast<T const*>(buffer(index));
        } else {
            return &data_[index];
        }
    }


In the SizeType template, we've misspelt the types std::uint8_t, std::uint16_t, std::uint32_t and std::uint64_t.  And we probably ought to fall back to std::size_t if none of those are large enough.  Using those fixed-size types does prevent the program from compiling on any platform that doesn't have all four, so I'd advise rethinking the logic there.  I'm not even convinced there's any benefit compared to simply using std::size_t for all instances.
It might be better to infer the size type from the template argument:
#include <concepts>

template<typename T, std::unsigned_integral auto Capacity>
class StaticVector {
public:
    using size_type = decltype(Capacity);


Capacity * sizeof (T) doesn't account for array padding.  Better to use sizeof (T[Capacity]) instead.

We have a bug in the single-element erase():

        aligned_buffer(idx)->~T();
        std::move(begin() + idx + 1, end(), begin() + idx);


We destructed the wrong element here - we should have destructed the last moved-from element:
        std::move(begin() + idx + 1, end(), begin() + idx);
        aligned_buffer(size_)->~T();


The template is effectively split depending on is_raw_storage, i.e. on whether the type T is trivially default-constructible.  I think it's probably better not to special-case these T, but instead to always consider the storage as uninitialised.
That makes for a much simpler implementation, at no loss of efficiency:
#include <algorithm>
#include <concepts>
#include <iterator>
#include <utility>

template<typename T, std::unsigned_integral auto Capacity>
class StaticVector {
public:
    using value_type = T;
    using iterator = T*;
    using const_iterator = const T*;
    using size_type = decltype(Capacity);

    StaticVector() : size_(0) {}

    ~StaticVector() {
        clear();
    }

    iterator push_back(const T& value) {
        if (size_ >= Capacity) {
            return end();  // Return end() to indicate failure
        }
        return new (begin() + size_++) T{value};
    }

    template<typename... Args>
    iterator emplace_back(Args&&... args) {
        if (size_ >= Capacity) {
            return end();  // Return end() to indicate failure
        }
        return new (begin() + size_++) T{std::forward<Args>(args)...};
    }

    iterator insert(const_iterator pos, const T& value) {
        auto const idx = static_cast<size_type>(pos - cbegin());
        if (idx > size_ || size_ >= Capacity) {
            return end();  // Return end() to indicate failure
        }
        new (begin() + size_) T{std::move(begin()[size_ - 1])};
        std::move_backward(begin() + idx, end() - 1, end());
        begin()[idx] = value;
        ++size_;
        return begin() + idx;
    }

    iterator erase(const_iterator pos) {
        auto idx = static_cast<size_type>(pos - cbegin());
        if (idx >= size_) {
            return end();  // Return end() to indicate failure
        }
        std::move(begin() + idx + 1, end(), begin() + idx);
        begin()[--size_].~T();
        return begin() + idx;
    }

    void clear() {
        for (auto &element: *this) {
            element.~T();
        }
        size_ = 0;
    }

    iterator begin() {
        return reinterpret_cast<iterator>(storage_);
    }
    const_iterator begin() const {
        return reinterpret_cast<const_iterator>(storage_);
    }
    const_iterator cbegin() const {
        return begin();
    }

    iterator end() {
        return begin() + size_;
    }
    const_iterator end() const {
        return begin() + size_;
    }
    const_iterator cend() const {
        return end();
    }

    size_type size() const {
        return size_;
    }
    std::size_t capacity() const {
        return Capacity;
    }
    bool empty() const {
        return size_ == 0;
    }

    auto& operator[](this auto&& self, size_type index) {
        return self.begin()[index];
    }

private:

    alignas(alignof(T)) char storage_[sizeof (T[Capacity])];
    size_type size_;
};


Consider throwing std::bad_alloc() when the capacity is exceeded, rather than requiring the caller to test the returned iterator.

With those changes, we have a good starting point for implementing the remaining member functions of std::vector.  In particular, we really need to implement our own copy/move constructor and assignment operator, as the compiler-generated ones will only work for trivially-constructible T.

Thanks for your answer. I just posted a revised implementation as an answer based on your suggestions. Would love to hear more comments!

I posted a separate question regarding the revised implementation. Please take a look! https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/292509/c-static-vector-revised-implementation

I post here a revised implementation based on on the various corrections/suggestions from @G. Sliepen, @Toby Speight and @Davislor, with the following changes:

Does not unnessarily distinguish between trivially and non-trivially constructible types. Uses correctly aligned byte array for all types.
Reworked API to more closely follow that of the std::vector
rule of 5

#include <cstdint>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstddef>
#include <limits>
#include <utility>
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T, std::size_t Capacity>
class StaticVector {
public:
    using value_type = T;
    using iterator = T*;
    using const_iterator = const T*;
    using reference = T&;
    using const_reference = const T&;
    using size_type = std::size_t;

    StaticVector() noexcept : size_(0) {}

    StaticVector(StaticVector const& other) : size_{other.size_}
    {
        std::uninitialized_copy(other.begin(), other.end(), begin());  
    } 

    StaticVector(StaticVector&& other) : size_{std::exchange(other.size_, 0)}
    {
        std::uninitialized_move(other.begin(), other.end(), begin());     
    } 

    StaticVector& operator=(const StaticVector& other) {
        if (this != &other) {
            clear();
            std::uninitialized_copy(other.begin(), other.end(), begin());
            size_ = other.size_;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    StaticVector& operator=(StaticVector&& other) {
        if (this != &other) {
            clear();
            std::uninitialized_move(other.begin(), other.end(), begin());
            size_ = std::exchange(other.size_, 0);
        }
        return *this;
    }

    ~StaticVector() {
        clear();
    }

    void push_back(const T& value) {
        if (size_ >= Capacity) {
            throw(std::length_error{"StaticVector::push_back: size exceeds capacity"});
        }
        new (begin() + size_++) T{value};
    }

    template<typename... Args>
    reference emplace_back(Args&&... args) {
        if (size_ >= Capacity) {
            throw(std::length_error{"StaticVector::emplace_back: size exceeds capacity"});
        }
        new (begin() + size_++) T{std::forward<Args>(args)...};
        return *(end() - 1);
    }

    iterator insert(const_iterator pos, const T& value) {
        auto const idx = static_cast<size_type>(pos - cbegin());
        if (idx > size_ || size_ >= Capacity) {
            throw(std::length_error{"StaticVector::insert: size exceeds capacity"});
        }
        new (begin() + size_) T{std::move(begin()[size_ - 1])};
        std::move_backward(begin() + idx, end() - 1, end());
        begin()[idx] = value;
        ++size_;
        return begin() + idx;
    }

    iterator erase(const_iterator pos) {
        auto idx = static_cast<size_type>(pos - cbegin());
        if (idx >= size_) {
            throw(std::range_error{"StaticVector::erase: index out of range"});
        }
        std::move(begin() + idx + 1, end(), begin() + idx);
        begin()[--size_].~T();
        return begin() + idx;
    }

    void clear() {
        for (auto &element : *this) {
            element.~T();
        }
        size_ = 0;
    }

    iterator begin() noexcept {
        return reinterpret_cast<iterator>(storage_);
    }
    const_iterator begin() const noexcept {
        return reinterpret_cast<const_iterator>(storage_);
    }
    const_iterator cbegin() const noexcept {
        return begin();
    }

    iterator end() noexcept {
        return begin() + size_;
    }
    const_iterator end() const noexcept {
        return begin() + size_;
    }
    const_iterator cend() const noexcept {
        return end();
    }

    size_type size() const noexcept {
        return size_;
    }

    static std::size_t capacity() noexcept {
        return Capacity;
    }

    bool empty() const noexcept {
        return size_ == 0;
    }

    reference at(size_type index) {
        if (index >= size_) {
            throw(std::out_of_range{"Index out of range"});
        }
        return begin()[index];
    }

    const_reference at(size_type index) const {
        if (index >= size_) {
            throw(std::out_of_range{"Index out of range"});
        }
        return begin()[index];
    }
 
    reference operator[](size_type index) noexcept {
        assert(index < size_);
        return begin()[index];
    }

    const_reference operator[](size_type index) const noexcept {
        assert(index < size_);
        return begin()[index];
    }

private:

    alignas(alignof(T)) char storage_[sizeof (T[Capacity])];
    size_type size_;
};

You can see a demonstration at https://godbolt.org/z/q9Ghc1en9
Any further sugggestions are welcome.

Move constructor looks broken - after std::exchange() isn't the std::uninitialized_move() a no-op because other.end() == other.begin()?

And the move-assign sets other.size to zero, but doesn't destruct any of its elements.  Probably worth posting as a new question, as this needs review of its own.

It's great to see you updated your code! But instead of posting it as an answer, consider creating a new question, so we can do a proper review of the new version.

Use constexpr where appropriate!

Consider defining struct Raw<T> { alignas(alignof(T)) char data[sizeof(T)]; };, and from there std::array<Raw<T>, Capacity> storage_;. This way you can index into storage_ naturally, while still using raw memory.

Here's the revised implementation if anyone is interested. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/292509/c-static-vector-revised-implementation
