C++ static vector revised implementation
This is a revised and expanded implementation of the original static_vector implementation based on the various suggestions and corrections from the kind people who reviewed the original version.The static_vector essentially implements a fixed_capacity contiguous container with strictly inline storage. Again, please kindly provide any review/comments on this new implementation, in particular with regards to constexpr-correctness and exception-correctness. For those who are interested and for reference, here's the original implementation:
original implementation
#ifndef OL_STATIC_VECTOR_HPP_
#define OL_STATIC_VECTOR_HPP_

#include <cstdint>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <limits>
#include <utility>
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#define OL_NO_EXCEPTIONS true

#define OL_CPP_VERSION_NEWER_THAN(x) (__cplusplus >= (x))
#define OL_CPP_VERSION_OLDER_THAN(x) (__cplusplus < (x))

#define OL_ASSERT(expr) assert(expr)

#if defined(__cpp_lib_unreachable) && __cpp_lib_unreachable >= 202202L
    #include <utility> // For std::unreachable
    #define OL_UNREACHABLE() std::unreachable()
#elif defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__clang__)
    #define OL_UNREACHABLE() __builtin_unreachable()
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
    #define OL_UNREACHABLE() __assume(0)
#else
    #define OL_UNREACHABLE() std::abort()
#endif

#if OL_NO_EXCEPTIONS //disable exceptions
#include <iostream>
    #define OL_THROW(type, msg) \
        do{ \
            if(not std::is_constant_evaluated()) { \
                std::cerr << msg << std::endl; \
                std::abort(); \
            } else { \
                assert(false); \
            } \
        } while (0)
#else // has exceptions
    #define OL_THROW(type, msg) throw type{msg}
#endif //OL_NO_EXCEPTIONS

#if defined(__GNUC__) && __GNUC__ >= 10 // For GCC 10 and later, constexpr placement new is available
    #define OL_GCC10_CONSTEXPR constexpr
#else
    #define OL_GCC10_CONSTEXPR
#endif // defined(__GNUC__) && __GNUC__ >= 10

#if OL_CPP_VERSION_NEWER_THAN(202002L) // C++20 or newer
    #include <memory>
    #define OL_CPP20_CONSTEXPR constexpr
    #define OL_MOVE(...) std::move(__VA_ARGS__)
    #define OL_MOVE_BACKWARD(...) std::move_backward(__VA_ARGS__)
    #define OL_CONSTRUCT_AT(...) std::construct_at(__VA_ARGS__)
    #define OL_DESTROY_AT(...) std::destroy_at(__VA_ARGS__)
    #define OL_DESTROY(...) std::destroy(__VA_ARGS__)
#else // c++17 or older
    #include <new>
    #define OL_CPP20_CONSTEXPR
    #define OL_MOVE(...) ol::internal::move(__VA_ARGS__)
    #define OL_MOVE_BACKWARD(...) ol::internal::move_backward(__VA_ARGS__)
    #define OL_CONSTRUCT_AT(...) ol::internal::construct_at(__VA_ARGS__)
    #define OL_DESTROY_AT(...) ol::internal::destroy_at(__VA_ARGS__)

    #if OL_CPP_VERSION_NEWER_THAN(201703L) 
        #define OL_DESTROY(...) std::destroy(__VA_ARGS__)
    #else
        #define OL_DESTROY(...) ol::internal::destroy(__VA_ARGS__)
    #endif //OL_CPP_VERSION_NEWER_THAN(201703L) 
#endif //OL_CPP_VERSION_NEWER_THAN(202002L) 

namespace ol{
namespace internal{

template<typename T, typename... Args>
inline OL_GCC10_CONSTEXPR auto construct_at(T* p, Args&&... args)
    noexcept(noexcept(::new((void*)0) T(std::declval<Args>()...)))
        -> decltype(::new((void*)0) T(std::declval<Args>()...))
{ return ::new((void*)p) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }

template <typename T>
inline void destroy_at(T* p) { p->~T(); }

template <typename It>
inline void destroy(It first, It last) 
{ 
    for (; first != last; ++first)
        ol::internal::destroy_at(std::addressof(*first)); 
}

template <typename InputIt, typename OutputIt>
inline constexpr OutputIt move(InputIt first, InputIt last, OutputIt d_first) {
    while (first != last) {
        *d_first++ = std::move(*first++);
    }
    return d_first;
}

template <typename BiDirItFrom, typename BiDirItTo>
inline constexpr BiDirItTo move_backward(BiDirItFrom first, BiDirItFrom last, BiDirItTo d_last) {
    while (first != last) {
        *--d_last = std::move(*--last);
    }
    return d_last;
}

template <typename InputIt, typename ForwardIt>
inline constexpr ForwardIt uninitialized_copy(InputIt first, InputIt last, ForwardIt d_first) {
    using src_value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type;
    using dest_value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIt>::value_type;
    using src_ref_type = typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::reference;
    using dest_ref_type = typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIt>::reference;

    static_assert(std::is_constructible_v<dest_value_type, decltype(*first)>,
        "result type must be constructible from value type of input range");

    constexpr bool is_copy_optimizable_v{
        std::is_trivial_v<src_value_type> &&
        std::is_trivial_v<dest_value_type> &&
        std::is_assignable_v<dest_ref_type, src_ref_type>};

    ForwardIt current =  d_first;
    try{
        for(; first != last; ++first, ++current) {
            if constexpr(is_copy_optimizable_v) {
                return std::copy(first, last, d_first);
            }else{
                std::construct_at(std::addressof(*current), *first);
                return current;
            }
        }
    } catch (...) {
        std::destroy(d_first, current);
        throw;
    }
}

template <typename InputIt, typename ForwardIt>
inline constexpr ForwardIt uninitialized_move(InputIt first, InputIt last, ForwardIt d_first)
{
    return std::uninitialized_copy(
        std::make_move_iterator(first), 
        std::make_move_iterator(last), d_first);
}

template<std::size_t Uint_>
using MinWidthSizeType = typename std::conditional_t<
    (Uint_ <= std::numeric_limits<std::uint8_t>::max()), std::uint8_t,
    typename std::conditional_t<
        (Uint_ <= std::numeric_limits<std::uint16_t>::max()), std::uint16_t,
        typename std::conditional_t<
            (Uint_ <= std::numeric_limits<std::uint32_t>::max()), std::uint32_t,
            uint64_t
        >
    >
>;

template <typename T, std::size_t Capacity>
struct sv_storage_base {
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef value_type* pointer;
    typedef value_type const* const_pointer;
    typedef T& reference;
    typedef T const& const_reference;
    typedef MinWidthSizeType<Capacity> size_type;
    static constexpr std::size_t capacity() noexcept { return Capacity; }
    static constexpr std::size_t max_size() noexcept { return Capacity; }
};

template <typename T>
struct zero_capcity_storage : public sv_storage_base<T, 0u> {
    using Base = sv_storage_base<T, 0u>;
    using typename Base::size_type;
    using typename Base::const_reference;
    static constexpr auto data() noexcept { return nullptr; }
    static constexpr std::size_t size() noexcept { return 0; }
    static constexpr void set_size(size_type) noexcept { OL_UNREACHABLE(); }        
    template <typename... Args>
    constexpr void emplace_back(Args...) noexcept { OL_UNREACHABLE(); };
    constexpr void insert(size_type, const_reference) noexcept { OL_UNREACHABLE(); }
    template <typename Range>
    constexpr void insert_range(size_type, Range&&) noexcept { OL_UNREACHABLE(); }
    template <typename Range>
    constexpr void push_back_range(Range&&) noexcept { OL_UNREACHABLE(); }
    template <typename... Args>
    constexpr void emplace(size_type, Args...) noexcept { OL_UNREACHABLE(); }
    constexpr void pop_from_back() noexcept { OL_UNREACHABLE(); };
    constexpr void erase(size_type) noexcept { OL_UNREACHABLE(); }
    constexpr void destroy_all() const noexcept {}
    template <typename InputIt>
    constexpr void destroy_range(InputIt, InputIt) const noexcept {}
};


template <typename T, std::size_t Capacity>
struct trivial_storage : public sv_storage_base<T, Capacity> {
    using Base = sv_storage_base<T, Capacity>;
    using typename Base::pointer;
    using typename Base::const_pointer;
    using typename Base::size_type;
    using typename Base::const_reference;

    constexpr pointer data() noexcept { return data_; }
    constexpr const_pointer data() const noexcept { return data_; }
    constexpr std::size_t size() const noexcept { return size_; }

    constexpr void set_size(size_type new_size) noexcept { size_ = new_size; }  

    constexpr void insert(size_type index, const_reference value) noexcept 
    { 
        OL_MOVE_BACKWARD(data() + index, data() + size_, data() + size_ + 1);
        ++size_;
        data_[index] = value;
    }

    template <typename... Args>
    constexpr void emplace(size_type index, Args... args) noexcept 
    { 
        OL_MOVE_BACKWARD(data() + index, data() + size_, data() + ++size_);
        data_[index] = T{std::forward<Args>(args)...};
    }

    template <typename... Args>
    constexpr void emplace_back(Args&&... args) noexcept 
    { 
        data_[size_++] = T{std::forward<Args>(args)...}; 
    }

    template <typename Range>
    constexpr void insert_range(size_type index, Range&& range) noexcept
    {
        size_type const range_size{static_cast<size_type>(
            std::distance(std::begin(range), std::end(range)))};
        pointer const move_first{data() + size_};
        pointer const move_last{move_first + range_size};

        OL_MOVE_BACKWARD(data() + index, move_first, move_last);

        for(const auto& elem : range){
            data_[index] = elem;
        }

        size_ += range_size;
    }

    template <typename Range>
    constexpr void push_back_range(Range&& range) noexcept
    {
        size_type const range_size{static_cast<size_type>(
            std::distance(std::begin(range), std::end(range)))};
        pointer const push_first{data() + size_};
        pointer const push_last{push_first + range_size};

        pointer push_pos{push_first};
        size_type push_idx{};
        auto const range_begin{std::begin(range)};

        for(; push_pos < push_last; push_pos++, push_idx++){
            *push_pos = *(range_begin + push_idx);
        }

        size_ += range_size;
    }

    constexpr void pop_from_back() noexcept { --size_; }

    constexpr void erase(size_type index) noexcept { 
        OL_MOVE(data() + index + 1, data() + size_--, data() + index);
    }

    constexpr void destroy_all() noexcept { size_ = 0; }
    
    template <typename InputIt>
    constexpr void destroy_range(InputIt first, InputIt last) noexcept { size_ -= (last - first); }
private:
    T data_[Capacity]{};
    size_type size_{};
};

template <typename T, std::size_t Capacity>
struct non_trivial_storage : public sv_storage_base<T, Capacity> {
    using Base = sv_storage_base<T, Capacity>;
    using typename Base::pointer;
    using typename Base::const_pointer;
    using typename Base::size_type;
    using typename Base::const_reference;

    pointer data() noexcept { return reinterpret_cast<pointer>(data_); }
    const_pointer data() const noexcept { return reinterpret_cast<const_pointer>(data_); }
    constexpr std::size_t size() const noexcept { return size_; }

    constexpr void set_size(size_type new_size) noexcept { size_ = new_size; }  

    void insert(size_type index, const_reference value) noexcept 
    { 
        OL_CONSTRUCT_AT(data() + size_, OL_MOVE(*(data() + size_ - 1)));
        OL_MOVE_BACKWARD(data() + index, data() + size_ - 1, data() + size_++);
        *(data() + index) = value;
    }

    template <typename... Args>
    void emplace(size_type index, Args... args) noexcept 
    { 
        OL_CONSTRUCT_AT(data() + size_, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        OL_MOVE_BACKWARD(data() + index, data() + size_ - 1, data() + size_++);
        *(data() + index) = T{std::forward<Args>(args)...};
    }

    template <typename... Args>
    void emplace_back(Args&&... args) 
        noexcept(noexcept(OL_CONSTRUCT_AT(data() + size(), std::forward<Args>(args)...))) 
    { 
        OL_CONSTRUCT_AT(data() + size_++, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    template <typename Range>
    void insert_range(size_type index, Range&& range) 
        noexcept(noexcept(std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<T> && std::is_nothrow_copy_assignable_v<T>)) 
    {
        size_type const range_size{static_cast<size_type>(
            std::distance(std::begin(range), std::end(range)))};
        pointer const move_first{data() + size_};
        pointer const move_last{move_first + range_size};

        for(pointer move_pos{move_first}; move_pos < move_last; move_pos++){
            OL_CONSTRUCT_AT(move_pos, OL_MOVE(*(move_pos - 1)));
        }

        OL_MOVE_BACKWARD(data() + index, move_first, move_last);

        for(const auto& elem : range){
            *(data() + index) = elem;
        }

        size_ += range_size;
    }

    template <typename Range>
    void push_back_range(Range&& range) 
        noexcept(noexcept(std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible_v<T>)) 
    {
        size_type const range_size{std::distance(std::begin(range), std::end(range))};
        pointer const construct_first{data() + size_};
        pointer const construct_last{construct_first + range_size};

        pointer construct_pos{construct_first};
        size_type construct_idx{};
        auto const range_begin{std::begin(range)};

        for(; construct_pos < construct_last; construct_pos++, construct_idx++){
            OL_CONSTRUCT_AT(construct_pos, *(range_begin + construct_idx));
        }

        size_ += range_size;
    }

    void pop_from_back() 
        noexcept(std::is_nothrow_destructible_v<T>)
    { OL_DESTROY_AT(data() + --size_); }

    void erase(size_type index) noexcept { 
        OL_MOVE(data() + index + 1, data() + size_, data() + index);
        OL_DESTROY_AT(data() + --size_);
    }

    void destroy_all() 
        noexcept(std::is_nothrow_destructible_v<T>) 
    { OL_DESTROY(data(), data() + size_); size_ = 0; }

    template <typename InputIt>
    void destroy_range(InputIt first, InputIt last) 
        noexcept(std::is_nothrow_destructible_v<T>)  
    { OL_DESTROY(first, last); size_ -= (last - first); }

private:
    alignas(alignof(T)) unsigned char data_[sizeof(T[Capacity])]{};
    size_type size_{};
};

template <typename T, std::size_t Capacity>
using sv_storage_type = std::conditional_t<
    Capacity == 0, 
        zero_capcity_storage<T>,
        std::conditional_t<std::is_trivial_v<T>, 
            trivial_storage<T, Capacity>,
            non_trivial_storage<T, Capacity>>>;

} //end ns internal

template<typename T, std::size_t Capacity>
class static_vector : private internal::sv_storage_type<T, Capacity>  {
public:
    using Base = internal::sv_storage_type<T, Capacity>;
    using typename Base::value_type;
    using typename Base::size_type;
    using typename Base::reference;
    using typename Base::const_reference;
    using iterator = typename Base::pointer;
    using const_iterator = typename Base::const_pointer;

    constexpr static_vector() noexcept = default;

    constexpr static_vector(static_vector const& other)
    {
        Base::set_size(other.size());
        ol::internal::uninitialized_copy(other.begin(), other.end(), begin());
    } 

    constexpr static_vector(static_vector&& other)
    {
        Base::set_size(other.size());
        ol::internal::uninitialized_move(other.begin(), other.end(), begin());
        other.clear();
    } 

    constexpr static_vector& operator=(const static_vector& other) {
        if (this != &other) {
            clear();
            Base::set_size(other.size());
            ol::internal::uninitialized_copy(other.begin(), other.end(), begin());
        }
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr static_vector& operator=(static_vector&& other) {
        if (this != &other) {
            clear();
            ol::internal::uninitialized_move(other.begin(), other.end(), begin());
            Base::set_size(other.size());
            other.clear();
        }
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr ~static_vector() noexcept(noexcept(clear())) {
        clear();
    }

    template <typename U, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<U, T>>>
    constexpr static_vector(std::initializer_list<U> list) 
        noexcept(noexcept(Base::push_back_range(list)))
    {
        if(list.size() >= max_size()){
            OL_THROW(std::length_error, "static_vector::initializer list ctor: size exceeds capacity");
        }
        Base::push_back_range(list);
    }

    constexpr iterator begin() noexcept {
        return Base::data();
    }
    constexpr const_iterator begin() const noexcept {
        return Base::data();
    }
    constexpr const_iterator cbegin() const noexcept {
        return begin();
    }

    constexpr iterator end() noexcept {
        return begin() + size();
    }
    constexpr const_iterator end() const noexcept {
        return begin() + size();
    }
    constexpr const_iterator cend() const noexcept {
        return end();
    }

    template <typename U, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible_v<T, U>>>
    OL_CPP20_CONSTEXPR void push_back(const U& value) 
        noexcept(OL_NO_EXCEPTIONS && std::is_nothrow_constructible_v<T>)
    {
        if (size() >= capacity()) {
            OL_THROW(std::length_error, "static_vector::push_back: size exceeds capacity");
        }
        Base::emplace_back(value);
    }

    template <typename U, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible_v<T, U>>>
    OL_CPP20_CONSTEXPR void push_back(U&& value) 
        noexcept(OL_NO_EXCEPTIONS && std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<T>) 
    {
        if (size() >= capacity()) {
            OL_THROW(std::length_error, "static_vector::push_back: size exceeds capacity");
        }
        Base::emplace_back(std::move(value));
    }

    OL_CPP20_CONSTEXPR void pop_back() 
        noexcept(OL_NO_EXCEPTIONS) 
    {
        if (empty()) {
            OL_THROW(std::length_error, "static_vector::pop_back: cannot remove from an empty container");
        }
        Base::pop_from_back();
    }

    template<typename... Args, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible_v<T, Args...>>>
    OL_CPP20_CONSTEXPR reference emplace_back(Args&&... args) 
        noexcept(OL_NO_EXCEPTIONS && std::is_nothrow_constructible_v<T>)
    {
        if (size() >= capacity()) {
            OL_THROW(std::length_error, "static_vector::emplace_back: size exceeds capacity");
        }
        Base::emplace_back(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        return *(end() - 1);
    }

    template <typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_copy_constructible_v<T>>>
    OL_CPP20_CONSTEXPR iterator insert(const_iterator pos, const_reference value) 
        noexcept(OL_NO_EXCEPTIONS && std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible_v<T>)
    {
        size_type const idx = static_cast<size_type>(pos - cbegin());
        if (idx > size() || size() >= capacity()) {
            OL_THROW(std::length_error, "static_vector::insert: size exceeds capacity");
        }
        Base::insert(idx, value);
        return begin() + idx;
    }

    template <typename... Args, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible_v<T, Args...>>>
    OL_CPP20_CONSTEXPR iterator emplace(const_iterator pos, Args... args) 
        noexcept(OL_NO_EXCEPTIONS && std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<T>)  
    {
        size_type const idx = static_cast<size_type>(pos - cbegin());
        if (idx > size() || size() >= capacity()) {
            OL_THROW(std::length_error, "static_vector::insert: size exceeds capacity");
        }
        Base::emplace(idx, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        return begin() + idx;
    }

    OL_CPP20_CONSTEXPR iterator erase(const_iterator pos) 
        noexcept(std::is_nothrow_destructible_v<T>) 
    {
        size_type const idx = static_cast<size_type>(pos - cbegin());
        if (idx >= size()) {
            OL_THROW(std::range_error, "static_vector::erase: index out of range");
        }
        Base::erase(idx);
        return begin() + idx;
    }

    constexpr void clear() noexcept(std::is_nothrow_destructible_v<T>) {
        Base::destroy_all();
    }

    constexpr std::size_t size() const noexcept {
        return Base::size();
    }

    static constexpr std::size_t capacity() noexcept {
        return Base::capacity();
    }

    static constexpr std::size_t max_size() noexcept {
        return Base::max_size();
    }

    constexpr bool empty() const noexcept {
        return size() == 0;
    }

    OL_CPP20_CONSTEXPR reference at(size_type index) noexcept(OL_NO_EXCEPTIONS) {
        if (index >= size()) {
            OL_THROW(std::out_of_range, "Index out of range");
        }
        return begin()[index];
    }

    OL_CPP20_CONSTEXPR const_reference at(size_type index) const noexcept(OL_NO_EXCEPTIONS) {
        if (index >= size()) {
            OL_THROW(std::out_of_range, "Index out of range");
        }
        return begin()[index];
    }
 
    OL_CPP20_CONSTEXPR reference operator[](size_type index) noexcept {
        OL_ASSERT(index < size());
        return begin()[index];
    }

    OL_CPP20_CONSTEXPR const_reference operator[](size_type index) const noexcept {
        OL_ASSERT(index < size());
        return begin()[index];
    }

    constexpr reference front() noexcept {
        return *begin();
    }
    constexpr const_reference front() const noexcept{
        return *begin();
    }

    OL_CPP20_CONSTEXPR reference back() noexcept{
        OL_ASSERT(not empty());
        return *(end() - 1);
    }
    OL_CPP20_CONSTEXPR const_reference back() const noexcept{
        OL_ASSERT(not empty());
        return *(end() - 1);
    }
}; //end struct static_vector



} //end ns ol

#undef OL_CPP_VERSION_NEWER_THAN
#undef OL_CPP_VERSION_OLDER_THAN
#undef OL_UNREACHABLE
#ifdef OL_NO_EXCEPTIONS
    #undef OL_NO_EXCEPTIONS
#endif
#ifdef OL_CPP20_CONSTEXPR
    #undef OL_NO_EXCEPTIONS
#endif
#undef OL_GCC10_CONSTEXPR
#undef OL_MOVE
#undef OL_MOVE_BACKWARD
#undef OL_CONSTRUCT_AT
#undef OL_DESTROY_AT
#undef OL_DESTROY
#undef OL_THROW
#undef OL_ASSERT

#endif /* OL_STATIC_VECTOR_HPP_ */


That's a lot of macros!  But at least you #undef them when done, which is good hygiene.  Note that it's safe to #undef something that was never defined:
//#ifdef OL_NO_EXCEPTIONS
    #undef OL_NO_EXCEPTIONS
//#endif

Also, why do we undef OL_NO_EXCEPTIONS again if OL_CPP20_CONSTEXPR is defined?
Some of these macros could be functions or aliases.  For example:
namespace ol::internal {
#if OL_CPP_VERSION_NEWER_THAN(202002L) // C++20 or newer

    using std::move;
    using std::move_backward;
    using std::construct_at;
    using std::destroy_at;
    using std::destroy;

#else  // pre-C++20 compatibility implementations
    
    template <typename InputIt, typename OutputIt>
    inline constexpr OutputIt move(InputIt first, InputIt last, OutputIt d_first);

    ⋮

    // etc

#endif
}


Although the comment suggests compatibility with "c++17 or older", it doesn't build with C++14 due to use of various trait_v traits types rather than using trait::value.  This hints that compatibility code has been added without proper testing.
Also, pre-C++20 uninitialized_copy needs OL_CPP20_CONSTEXPR in place of constexpr because to the try/catch.  Also constexpr destructors need C++20, so same change there.
OL_NO_EXCEPTIONS requires C++20 due to use of std::is_constant_evaluated().

In MinWidthSizeType, we have a hard dependency on the optional types std::uint8_t, std::uint16_t, etc.  I don't think there's a good reason not to use the guaranteed-present _least variants here.  Perhaps we should have std::size_t as the final fallback?

We have a bug in non_trivial_storage::insert() (and also in its emplace():

    OL_MOVE_BACKWARD(data() + index, data() + size_ - 1, data() + size_++);


The equivalent code in trivial_storage avoids this unsequenced modification of size_.

I'm not convinced there's a benefit to treating trivial types differently from non-trivial ones.  Do you have any benchmark evidence that it makes a difference at all?  I'd be inclined to treat all content types the same unless presented with strong evidence that the extra code is worthwhile.
This "optimisation" is confusing to read, because the loop never loops:

    for(; first != last; ++first, ++current) {
        if constexpr(is_copy_optimizable_v) {
            return std::copy(first, last, d_first);
        }else{
            std::construct_at(std::addressof(*current), *first);
            return current;
        }
    }


I think it's wrong - the else case needs to construct the whole range:
    if constexpr(is_copy_optimizable_v) {
        return std::copy(first, last, d_first);
    }

    for(; first != last; ++first, ++current) {
            std::construct_at(std::addressof(*current), *first);
    }
    return current;

This example shows that when you add complexity, you need to ensure that all paths are covered by your unit tests.

I don't understand the point of this:

template <typename InputIt, typename ForwardIt>
inline constexpr ForwardIt uninitialized_move(InputIt first, InputIt last, ForwardIt d_first)
{
    return std::uninitialized_copy(
        std::make_move_iterator(first), 
        std::make_move_iterator(last), d_first);
}


Why not simply use std::uninitialized_move()?  Or was this intended to call the internal uninitialized_copy(), for pre-C++17 targets?  That's another test-coverage gap if so.

In insert_range(), we have:

    for(pointer move_pos{move_first}; move_pos < move_last; move_pos++){
        internal::construct_at(move_pos, internal::move(*(move_pos - 1)));
    }

    internal::move_backward(data() + index, move_first, move_last);


Move-constructing the last element n times probably isn't the most efficient implementation.  I think we should uninitialized_move() a range of elements and move_backward() the remainder - but we'll need to have different execution paths according to whether the inserted range is to straddle the current end or not.
We've been careful to determine whether this function is noexcept - but we've fallen far short of providing the strong exception guarantee.  Can we attempt to get back to the initial state if an exception is thrown?

destroy_range() is never called.  And I don't think it ever should be: it violates the container's invariant (that elements between 0 and size_ are alive, and no others).

I think this test should be >, not >=:

   if(list.size() >= max_size()){


Conversely, in emplace() and insert(), the index test needs to be idx >= size(), not idx > size().

U is a forwarding reference here, not an rvalue reference:

template <typename U>
void push_back(U&& value) 
{
    Base::emplace_back(std::move(value));
}


We should be using a single function and std::forward<U>(), not std::move()

We can replace size(), capacity() and max_size() with using, since they are exactly the Base members.

back() could be implemented in terms of rbegin(), when we complete the set of iterator accessors.  I don't see why these have a debug assertion, but front() does not.
